# Convert a Woocommerce hooked function into a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

A previous question of mine [was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49565625/1887218) and included two separate functions, one using a WooCommerce `add_action` hook. How can I take this answer and convert it to a **shortcode** that I could add to a product page?

I am using a page builder (Divi Builder) to create a custom layout/template of WooCommerce product pages. Having a shortcode will allow me to paste the shortcode into the builder, and have it output the result anywhere within that template structure.

This is the code I need turned into a shortcode:

```
// Utility funtion: getting and formtting product data
function format_product_data_output( $the_id ){
    $empty =  __( '<em>(empty)</em>', 'woocommerce' );

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
    $product = wc_get_product( $the_id );

    // Only wc_get_price_to_display() respect if product is to be displayed with or without including taxes
    $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ) );
    $sale_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );
    $sale_price = ! empty( $sale_price ) ? wc_price($sale_price) : $empty;

    $size = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_size' );
    $size = ! empty( $size ) ? get_term_by( 'slug', $size, 'pa_size' )->name : $empty;

    $stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $stock_qty = ! empty( $stock_qty ) ? $stock_qty : $empty;

    $output = '
    <ul>
        <li class="fs-data-price">'.$price.'</li>
        <li class="fs-data-size">Size: '.$size.'</li>
        <li class="fs-data-sale">'.$sale_price.' Preferred Customer Price</li>
        <li class="fs-data-stock">Quantity in Stock: '.$stock_qty.'</li>
    </ul>';

    return $output;
}

//
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'custom_table_after_single_product' );
function custom_table_after_single_product(){
    global $product;

    $output = '<div class="fs-product-data-wrapper">';

    // Variable products
    if( $product->is_type('variable'))
    {
        // Get available variations in the variable product
        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

        if( count($available_variations) > 0 ){
            foreach( $available_variations as $variation )
                $output .= format_product_data_output( $variation['variation_id'] );
        }
    }
    // Simple products
    elseif( $product->is_type('simple'))
    {
        $output .= format_product_data_output( $product->get_id() );
    }
    else return; // Exit

    echo $output .= '</div>'; // Display
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this already? [WordPress' Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2:** Try the following:

```
add_shortcode("variation_table", "custom_available_variations_table");
function custom_available_variations_table( $atts ) {

    global $post;

    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id'    => $post->ID
        ),
        $atts, 'variation_table'
    );

    if( is_admin() ) return; // Only on front end

    $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']); // Get the WC_Product Object

    $output = '<div class="fs-product-data-wrapper">';

    // Variable products
    if( $product->is_type('variable'))
    {
        // Get available variations in the variable product
        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

        if( count($available_variations) > 0 ){
            foreach( $available_variations as $variation )
                $output .= format_product_data_output( $variation['variation_id'] );
        }
    }
    // Simple products
    elseif( $product->is_type('simple'))
    {
        $output .= format_product_data_output( $product->get_id() );
    }
    else return; // Exit

    return $output .= '</div>'; // return always for a shortcode
}

// Utility funtion: getting and formtting product data
function format_product_data_output( $the_id ){
    $empty =  __( '<em>(empty)</em>', 'woocommerce' );

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
    $product = wc_get_product( $the_id );

    // Only wc_get_price_to_display() respect if product is to be displayed with or without including taxes
    $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ) );
    $sale_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );
    $sale_price = ! empty( $sale_price ) ? wc_price($sale_price) : $empty;

    $size = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_size' );
    $size = ! empty( $size ) ? get_term_by( 'slug', $size, 'pa_size' )->name : $empty;

    $stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $stock_qty = ! empty( $stock_qty ) ? $stock_qty : $empty;

    $output = '
    <ul>
        <li class="fs-data-price">'.$price.'</li>
        <li class="fs-data-size">Size: '.$size.'</li>
        <li class="fs-data-sale">'.$sale_price.' Preferred Customer Price</li>
        <li class="fs-data-stock">Quantity in Stock: '.$stock_qty.'</li>
    </ul>';

    return $output;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

**SHORTCODE USAGE:**

- In a product page: `[variation_table]` (without any need of define an ID)
- Anywhere defining the product ID: `[variation_table id='27']`

Comment: It displays correctly on the frontend, but it caused the wp-admin post to have a white screen once it was saved with the shortcode in it. PHP server error is on line 18 it says. Is there a way to make sure it only runs on the frontend, and not in the admin area?

Comment: This is working great. Any way to easily have the foreach output of the variations be ordered by the price? Or, more ideally, by the same custom order of the pa_size attribute terms found in the backend of the WooCommerce Attribute terms? Currently, the order is how they show within the Product setup: https://freshysites.d.pr/tf6CwX But it would be nice to change this order on the frontend output.

Comment: @Garconis You should ask a new question related to this new requirement…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49945108/sort-a-woocommerce-variation-foreach-output-by-their-price

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Wordpress Shortcode Api

Implementation would be something like this:

```
 function format_product_data_output( $the_id ){
        $empty =  __( '<em>(empty)</em>', 'woocommerce' );

        // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
        $product = wc_get_product( $the_id );

        // Only wc_get_price_to_display() respect if product is to be displayed with or without including taxes
        $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ) );
        $sale_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );
        $sale_price = ! empty( $sale_price ) ? wc_price($sale_price) : $empty;

        $size = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_size' );
        $size = ! empty( $size ) ? get_term_by( 'slug', $size, 'pa_size' )->name : $empty;

        $stock_qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        $stock_qty = ! empty( $stock_qty ) ? $stock_qty : $empty;

        $output = '
        <ul>
            <li class="fs-data-price">'.$price.'</li>
            <li class="fs-data-size">Size: '.$size.'</li>
            <li class="fs-data-sale">'.$sale_price.' Preferred Customer Price</li>
            <li class="fs-data-stock">Quantity in Stock: '.$stock_qty.'</li>
        </ul>';

        return $output;
    }

add_shortcode( 'format', 'format_product_data_output' );
```

I have added the add_shortcode line,

The explanation is that the shortcode 'format' does the 'format_product_data_output' function.