# Showing all prices for variable products listed instead of range of prices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Is there any way to replace range price of variable products in woocommerce on shop page and instead of it showing a list of variations and their prices per product in order to display variations to customer and showing 'Add to Cart' for all type of products not 'Choose an Option' for variable products.

I have tested a lot of code snippets without success.

Below code is the closest to what I need, I used code suggested here [Get specific product attribute name and value for each WooCommerce variation of a variable product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586296/get-specific-product-attribute-name-and-value-for-each-woocommerce-variation-of) and changed it. but still the problem is that part of attribute is not shown.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variable_price_html', 10, 2 );
function custom_variable_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    
    if(!is_admin()){
        
        if(is_shop()){

            $product_attribute_slug = 'ابعاد-فرش';

            $targeted_taxonomy = 'pa_' . $product_attribute_slug;

            $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

            $output = '<div>';

            foreach( $available_variations as $variation_data ){

                if( $variation_data['display_price'] === $variation_data['display_regular_price'] ) {
                    $price_to_display = wc_price( $variation_data['display_price'] );
                } else {
                    $variation = wc_get_product($variation_data['variation_id']); // Get the WC_Product_Variation Object
                    $price_to_display = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array('price' => $variation->get_sale_price() ) );
                }

                foreach ( $variation_data['attributes'] as $variation_attribute => $term_slug ) {
                    // Get the taxonomy slug
                    $taxonomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $variation_attribute );

                    // Get the correct product attribute term value for this variation
                    if( $taxonomy === $targeted_taxonomy ) {
                        // Get the attribute value term name
                        $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy )->name;
                    }
                }

                $output .= '<span>' . $term_name . ':' . wc_attribute_label( $targeted_taxonomy ) . ':' . strip_tags($price_to_display) . '</span><br>';
            }

            $output .= '</div>';

            $price = $output;

            return $price;
        } else {
            
            return $price;
        }
    
    } else {
        
        return $price;
    }
}
```

what I get is:
[image]

but I need something Like this:
[image]

As I noticed

> $term_name

variable in code is empty.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is not a real code attempt provided in the question. What you are asking is a real development, that include many questions at once, so something too broad. Also please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I added more detail to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: set taxonomy as follow and use it in `get_term_by()` function:

```
$taxonomy = 'pa_ابعاد-فرش';
```